# Tried to fix loops in kernel upgrades that said couldn't find UUID and fix with RESUME but always gave me generic kernel instead of updating it

Tags: uuid

I had updated my Kubuntu 23.04 to 23.10 and though I was told that in everyday updates, that the system not finding the right UUID is normal (which I never understood because why make new kernels/kernel headers if it is just going to be cycling 3 or 4 times, each time suggesting that I fix the RESUME problem while saying I'm likely missing a bunch of graphics card files, and finally settling on a generic kernel). Well, it got worse upon the upgrade and I figured out that somewhere along the way it lost track of the main UUID and I thought I found and fixed it and created a UUID-correct RESUME file in /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d and now it will only boot into recovery mode but it does find 2 23.04 points on other partitions if all else fails. Which it is beginning to look like. What do I do now? I thought I found the solution in trying the drive's UUID but no luck.
Thanks,
Michael The Gamer
PS- andrew my apologies, I thought I was posting my own question. I shall review more closely from now on.  M